# Using Java to capture an area of the screen and identify text found there

Tags: java, ocr

This question may be beyond the scope of a simple answer here at stack **overflow**, but my hope is that it will lead me to be able to formulate several more specific questions to get where I need to be.

I want to write a program that searches a buffered image for text and returns it as a string. I don't want to write an entire OCR program, but would rather use an API that is freely available such as tesseract. Unfortunately I've been unable to find a Java API for tesseract.

I know that the font is arial and I know it's size. I am wondering if that will help.

I've already managed to capture the screen, but I'm not sure how to accomplish the next step of identifying the text found in the image.

**the question**

How can I implement a simple OCR function into my java program?

Comment: simple OCR functions exist?! :D

Comment: You do have a point, but I was hoping since I know the font and font size that it would be more simple than usual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OCR implementation is complicated, but using an SDK like http://asprise.com/product/ocr/index.php?lang=java is simple.

Comment: Yes, but it is unfortunately not freely available.

Comment: Actually, taking a tenth look at the site, I realize now that it is freely available since I will not be distributing this program.

Comment: I saw this project a while ago. http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaocr. It has a Swing interface, but the source file is included. You could maybe use their engine.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [tesjeract](http://code.google.com/p/tesjeract/) or [tess4j](http://tess4j.sf.net) wrapper of Tesseract API. Be sure to rescale you images to 300 DPI since screenshots' resolution (72 or 96 DPI) is in general not adequate for OCR purpose.